# How to add a button on Android that is not covering screen?

Tags: android

I need a button in android app to not be visible on screen when it is not used. Entire screen is covered by webview and I need a button to be only visible when needed. How can I do that?

I know how to make button visible/hidden but how I know user wants it visible? How can I get the user intention that he needs the button to be visible?

Comment: what do you mean by "needed"? you should add detail on when and how you need it...

Answer (score 0):

Use this when condition is match

```
yourButton.setVisibility(View.GONE); // hide view

yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //visible view
```

Comment: I know how to make button visible/invisible but how can I let user make it, what is the possible user input to let me know he wants the button to be visible.

Comment: make a check box and let user choose if he want  button to visible .

Comment: check logic in code if checkbox is true then show if not then hide button

Comment: I don't want checkbox visible on screen, if it was visible I would just make button visible. I want hidden button that is revealed what user do something, what is that something?

Comment: can you explain it by giving a use case.

Comment: I have webview covering entire screen. I need button with settings. I don't want button to be visible on screen as it would be covering the webview so the button is hidden. Then user wants to see the settings. User do SOMETHING and I set buttons visibility to View.VISIBLE. What is that "SOMETHING"?

Comment: may be scrolling or touch on view ??

Answer (score 0):

set its visibiliy programmatically:

```
buttonView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

or

```
buttonView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

`GONE` completely removes the button from the layout.

`INVISIBLE` hides the button, but it still takes up space in the layout

to make the button visible again:

```
buttonView.setVisibiliy(View.VISIBLE)
```